# Please help, jsf icefaces webapp unable to run in netbean

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

Good morning everyone,

I came across a tutorial online that shows how to create a popup dialogue box. The tutorial started with the configurations of my environment like adding all the possible .jar file that is required to successfully create and run an ICE faces project.

I added all the jar files successfully, created the project and typed all the codes that were given to me by the tutorial.

But when I tried to run the `icefaces project`, netbean always pops up an error message in an output panel.

I suspect the problem to be coming from a configuration I omitted or something else I don't know.

So if anyone of you could help me identify why my project is not working when am trying to run it, I'll be very happy.

Here is the error netbean show me when I try to run it:

```
In-place deployment at C:\JavaProjects\new app\First Ice Popup\build \web deploy?DEFAULT=C:\JavaProjects\new  app\First Ice Popup\build \web&name=First_Ice_Popup& contextroot=/First_Ice_Popup&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3.1.2 Error occurred during  deployment: Exception while loading the app :  java.lang.IllegalStateException:  ContainerBase.addChild: start:  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:  java.lang.RuntimeException:  com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:  Source Document: jar:file:/C:/JavaProjects /new%20app/First%20Ice%20Popup/build /web/WEB-INF/lib/icefaces-compat.jar!/META- INF/faces-config.xml Cause: Class ' com.icesoft.faces.component.effect.ApplyEffectRenderer'
C : \JavaProjects\new app\First  Ice Popup \build \web
deploy ? DEFAULT = C : \JavaProjects\new  app\First  Ice Popup \build\web & name = First_Ice_Popup & contextroot =/ First_Ice_Popup & force = true  failed on  GlassFish Server 3.1 . 2 Error  occurred during deployment : Exception while  loading the app  :  java . lang . IllegalStateException : ContainerBase . addChild :  start :  org . apache . catalina . LifecycleException :  java . lang . RuntimeException :  com . sun . faces . config . ConfigurationException : Source Document :  jar : file :/ C :/ JavaProjects / new % 20app / First % 20Ice % 20Popup / build / web / WEB - INF / lib / icefaces - compat . jar !/ META - INF / faces - config . xml
   Cause : Class ' com.icesoft.faces.component.effect.ApplyEffectRenderer
'is missing a runtime dependency :  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache /commons/logging/LogFactory. Please see  server.log for more details. C:\JavaProjects\new app\First Ice Popup\nbproject\build-impl.xml: 724: The module has not been deployed. See
 java . lang . NoClassDefFoundError :  org / apache / commons / logging / LogFactory . Please  see server . log  for  more details . C : \JavaProjects\new app\First  Ice Popup \nbproject\build - impl . xml : 724 : The  module  has not been deployed .
Seethe server log for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing a few runtime dependencies such as commons-logging.

The following JARs are required to use ICEfaces:

```
backport-util-concurrent.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-collections.jar
commons-digester.jar
commons-fileupload.jar
commons-logging.jar
commons-logging-api.jar
el-api.jar
icefaces.jar (incl. std. JSF comp. support) 
just-ice.jar (without std. JSF comp. support)
icefaces-comps.jar
xercesImpl.jar
xml-apis.jar
```

A few of them are already included in the Glassfish server, but you have to check the commons-dependencies.

Comment: Thank you soooo much sir,!! I appreciate am sooo grateful!! Though av not tried it.